# Matching and transposing data between dataframes

Tags: r

I'm wondering if anyone can suggest a better code for matching and transposing data between 2 dataframes.  For example, I have a dataframe

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "A", class = "factor")), .Names = "id", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), class = "data.frame")


    id
1   A
2   A
3   A
4   A
5   A
6   A
7   A
8   A
9   A
10  A
11  A
12  A
```

In this dataframe `df1`, I want to create a new column `data` using another dataframe `df2`:

```
df2 <- structure(list(id = structure(1:3, .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), 
    x1 = c(9L, 4L, 9L), x2 = c(7L, 2L, 8L), x3 = c(7L, 6L, 7L
    ), x4 = c(9L, 5L, 5L), x5 = c(8L, 8L, 4L), x6 = c(7L, 4L, 
    6L), x7 = c(9L, 8L, 5L), x8 = c(7L, 7L, 8L), x9 = c(5L, 5L, 
    5L), x10 = c(4L, 2L, 8L), x11 = c(9L, 1L, 4L), x12 = c(8L, 
    6L, 5L)), .Names = c("id", "x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x5", 
"x6", "x7", "x8", "x9", "x10", "x11", "x12"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))


    id  x1  x2  x3  x4  x5  x6  x7  x8  x9  x10 x11 x12
1   A   9   7   7   9   8   7   9   7   5   4   9   8
2   B   4   2   6   5   8   4   8   7   5   2   1   6
3   C   9   8   7   5   4   6   5   8   5   8   4   5
```

Essentially, I want to first match columns `id` in `df1` and `df2`, and then transpose data from `df2[,2:13]` into a new column `df1$data` to give the following result:

```
result <- structure(list(id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "A", class = "factor"), data = c(9L, 
    7L, 7L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 9L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 9L, 8L)), .Names = c("id", 
    "data"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))

    id  data
1   A   9
2   A   7
3   A   7
4   A   9
5   A   8
6   A   7
7   A   9
8   A   7
9   A   5
10  A   4
11  A   9
12  A   8
```

I'm able to achieve the result with

```
df1$data <- t(df2[unique(match(df1$id, df2$id)),2:13])
```

but this seems "messy" to me... can anyone tell me if there is a better/shorter/more intuitive way I should be doing this?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this solution... Maybe just replace `2:13` with `-1`

Comment: Is there really anything that connects `df1` to `df2`?, i.e. the first row of `df1` corresponds to `x1` in `df2` etc...will you ever have a different number of rows in `df1` than columns in `df2`? If not - this looks like a roundabout way of doing `library(reshape2); melt(df2, id.vars = "id")` or whatever your preferred method of going from wide to long data happens to be...

Comment: Hi Chase, yes there will always be 12 rows in df1 and 12 columns in df2, and these always correspond to eachother.  I will always be going from long to wide but it also requires the matching before that.  thanks!

Comment: What exactly is being matched? The only thing that comes from `df1` is the value of `A`...which you get by default when you melt the data into long format. Granted, for this example - you would need to then filter/subset out the `B` and `C` rows from the melted data.frame, but otherwise - your code above is equivalent to `melt(df2, id.vars = "id")`

Comment: What makes code "better" and "more intuitive" is highly subjective and it wouldn't surprise me if someone would vote to close the question as 'Primarily opinion-based'.

Comment: Hi Chase, the data provided was just a very simple example, but in my real data "id" data varies (A will not always be the only thing from df1).  thanks!

Comment: I must be missing something inherent to your problem that hasn't been communicated. Is there any "new" information that comes from `df1`? Or did you create it simply so that you can have multiple observations/rows for `id == A`? From the code above and the comments, it still seems to be that simply reshaping the `df2` object is all you're trying to do. Did you try running the code suggested above to reshape your data?

Comment: Hello Chase, first - thanks for your help, i really appreciate it!  to answer your query, these are just examples I made up for illustration.  In my real data, df1 contains many additional data that I left out of this example.  I understand your suggestion about reshaping df2, however the two dataframes contain unique data and thus I need to match between the two (can't just reshape df2).  This was just a simple example I made up here.

Comment: gotcha - well reshaping `df2` and then merging it to a more representative example of `df1` may be a more idiomatic alternative to what you're doing above...but if what you're doing works - don't mess with it! Also, providing a more representative example dataset would help others hone in on more appropriate answers.