# Adding columns to each in a list of dataframes

Tags: r

This is a follow-up to my earlier question at [Matching and transposing data between dataframes in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26108549/matching-and-transposing-data-between-dataframes-in-r).  I have a list of dataframes, for example:

```
dfs <- structure(list(df1 = structure(list(id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "A", class = "factor")), .Names = "id", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L)), df2 = structure(list(id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "B", class = "factor")), .Names = "id", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L)), df3 = structure(list(id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "C", class = "factor")), .Names = "id", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))), .Names = c("df1", "df2", "df3"))
```

In each dataframe in the list, I would like to create a new column `data` based on matching and transposing from a fourth dataframe `df4`:

```
df4 <- structure(list(id = structure(1:3, .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), 
    x1 = c(9L, 4L, 9L), x2 = c(7L, 2L, 8L), x3 = c(7L, 6L, 7L
    ), x4 = c(9L, 5L, 5L), x5 = c(8L, 8L, 4L), x6 = c(7L, 4L, 
    6L), x7 = c(9L, 8L, 5L), x8 = c(7L, 7L, 8L), x9 = c(5L, 5L, 
    5L), x10 = c(4L, 2L, 8L), x11 = c(9L, 1L, 4L), x12 = c(8L, 
    6L, 5L)), .Names = c("id", "x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x5", 
"x6", "x7", "x8", "x9", "x10", "x11", "x12"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

I can achieve this using separate lines of code for each dataframe in the list, such as

```
dfs$df1$data <- t(df4[unique(match(dfs$df1$id, df4$id)), 2:13])
dfs$df2$data <- t(df4[unique(match(dfs$df2$id, df4$id)), 2:13])
dfs$df3$data <- t(df4[unique(match(dfs$df3$id, df4$id)), 2:13])
```

but i'm sure there must be a more efficient and shorter way to do this.  I'm pretty sure I need to use `lapply` but cannot figure out how to make that work.  For example, I can use

```
lapply(dfs, function(d) t(df4[unique(match(d$id, df4$id)), 2:13]))
```

to give the result as vectors, but I can't figure out how to insert these as new columns called `data` in each dataframe in the list.  Does anyone know how I could do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe `Map(cbind, dfs, lapply(dfs, function(d) t(df4[unique(match(d$id, df4$id)), -1])))`?

Comment: @smci how many people do you think follow the "insert" tag?

Comment: When you get to these levels of pain in R, I suggest you may want to consider [Python pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/). If that's acceptable to you, I'll show you the pandas answer, which will be infinitely more readable and maintainable.

Comment: @GSee, I think that's irrelevant. It's certainly relevant to [tag:dataframes],[tag:lapply]. Edit the tags as you see fit.

Comment: smci - haven't used python before although it's been recommended to me before and i'm thus becoming more and more interested.  i'm just looking for a quick fix now but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @smci - I'm genuinely curious how this would be much simpler in pandas. One line of R code is not exactly complex.

Comment: @thelatemail: do you not distinguish between a line of illegible, write-only code vs a line of legible, easily understandable code? And spare a thought for maintainability.

Comment: @smci - of course I do - hence why I asked. I'm genuinely curious to see a pandas answer as I have no knowledge of it. I think it's also a bit of hyperbole to call the answer I suggested illegible.

Comment: @thelatemail: I was referring to the OP's `dfs$df1$data <- t(df4[unique(match(dfs$df1$id, df4$id)), 2:13])` which is serious spaghetti. I'll try to post the pandas solution by next week.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an attempt using `lapply`:

```
lapply(dfs, function(x) {
  cbind(
       x,
       new=unlist(df4[match(x$id[1],df4$id),-1])
       )
})

#$df1
#    id new
#x1   A   9
#x2   A   7
#x3   A   7
#...
#
#$df2
#    id new
#x1   B   4
#x2   B   2
#x3   B   6
#...
# 
#$df3
#    id new
#x1   C   9
#x2   C   8
#x3   C   7
#...
```

Comment: brilliant, thanks thelatemail!  you pretty much saved me a bazillion lines of code